# Flutter Bloc equatable state not updating with a Map of Strings property

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

My Bloc state isn't updating and I've found the problem to potentially be a `Map<String, Map<String, String>` property that isnt being compared properly. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the state updates when the other properties change, just not when the `imageUrls` property updates.

**These are my state objects**

```dart
abstract class PropertiesState extends Equatable {
  const PropertiesState();
}

class PropertiesLoaded extends PropertiesState {
  final int count;
  final List<Property> properties;
  final Map<String, Map<String, String>> imageUrls;

  const PropertiesLoaded({
    this.count,
    this.properties,
    this.imageUrls,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [count, properties, imageUrls];
}
```

The imageUrls field can have any string key/value pairs.
I haven't been able to find any information on how I should do this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think it should work well, however, change  Map<String, Map<String, String>> to dynamic, just as a test, Tell me the result

Comment: You're right it does work. Maps compare easily. Turns out I was changing a property on the imageUrl instead of creating a new map with each event. I get why properties on classes need to be immutable for equatable to work now too

Answer (score 7):

Because Equatable is trying to compare the reference of your List or Map object because they are not primitive type like int. You can try deep copy a Map object (using Map.from()) and replace the old one, and use hash code to do the comparison.

Comment: how to use hash code to do the comparison?

Comment: @temirbek pass in equatable props `hashCode` instead of just map property. In this example it would be:
`List<Object> get props => [count, properties, imageUrls.hashCode];`

Answer (score 6):

From [Docs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating)

> **Equatable** properties should always be copied rather than modified. If
> an **Equatable** class contains a **List** or **Map** as properties, be sure to
> use **List.from** or **Map.from** respectively to ensure that equality is
> evaluated based on the values of the properties rather than the
> reference.

```
emit(PropertiesLoaded(count, properties,
Map<String, Map<String, String>>.from(imageUrls)));
```