# State in BLoC changes its value before calling emit(), but Equatable doesn't recognize the state change

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, cubit

My problem is that when I'm calling a Cubit function it changes a value before I hit emit. Because of that, the Cubit cannot detect that there was a change in the state and the `emit()` won't work.

I solved the problem by creating a random number each time the function is called so that the cubit can recognize the state change. I just want to know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm already using the Equatable package.

```dart
part of 'survey_cubit.dart';

abstract class SurveyState extends Equatable {
  const SurveyState({
    required this.business,
    required this.locals,
    this.local = Local.en,
    this.status = BusinessStatus.setup,
    this.review = Review.empty,
    this.questionIndex = 0,
    this.answersId = const [],
    this.questionsId = const [],
    this.random = 0.0,
  });

  final Business business;
  final List<Local> locals;
  final Local local;
  final BusinessStatus status;
  final Review review;
  final int questionIndex;
  final List<int> answersId;
  final List<int> questionsId;
  final double random;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        business,
        locals,
        local,
        status,
        review,
        questionIndex,
        answersId,
        questionsId,
        random,
      ];

  SurveyState copyWith({
    Business? business,
    List<Local>? locals,
    Local? local,
    BusinessStatus? status,
    Review? review,
    int? questionIndex,
    List<int>? answersId,
    List<int>? questionsId,
    double? random,
  });
}

class SurveyInitial extends SurveyState {
  const SurveyInitial({
    required super.business,
    required super.locals,
    super.local = Local.en,
    super.status = BusinessStatus.setup,
    super.review = Review.empty,
    super.questionIndex = 0,
    super.answersId = const [],
    super.questionsId = const [],
    super.random = 0.0,
  });

  @override
  SurveyState copyWith({
    Business? business,
    List<Local>? locals,
    Local? local,
    BusinessStatus? status,
    Review? review,
    int? questionIndex,
    List<int>? answersId,
    List<int>? questionsId,
    double? random,
  }) =>
      SurveyInitial(
        business: business ?? this.business,
        locals: locals ?? this.locals,
        local: local ?? this.local,
        status: status ?? this.status,
        review: review ?? this.review,
        questionIndex: questionIndex ?? this.questionIndex,
        answersId: answersId ?? this.answersId,
        questionsId: questionsId ?? this.questionsId,
        random: random ?? this.random,
      );
}
```

```dart
class SurveyCubit extends Cubit<SurveyState> {
  SurveyCubit(DeviceInfo deviceInfo)
      : super(
    SurveyInitial(
            business: deviceInfo.business!,
            locals: deviceInfo.locals,
          ),
        );
  void onRemoveReview(int questionId) {
    final Review review = state.review;
    review.reviewedQuestions.removeWhere(
      (element) => element.questionId == questionId,
    );
    final List<int> questionsId = state.questionsId;
    questionsId.remove(questionId);
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        review: review,
        answersId: [],
        questionsId: questionsId,
        random: Random().nextDouble(),
      ),
    );
    print(state.questionsId);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an error about removing from a final list " questionsId.remove(questionId)". Looking about the rest. Maybe it was the issue, without your random number and with a list not changing, the state was equal to the old one.

Comment: Similar to (but not a duplicate of; root cause was two references pointing to the same object, not failure to create a new reference at all) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895683/flutter-bloc-equatable-state-not-updating-with-a-map-of-strings-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cubit, you assign `state.questionsId` (the old state's list) to a new variable. This doesn't create a new list; it just adds a new reference to the old one. The object ID is still the same. When you emit the new state, Equatable looks at the object ID and sees that it's identical and thinks the two states are the same.

From the Bloc [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating):

> Equatable properties should always be copied rather than modified. If
> an Equatable class contains a List or Map as properties, be sure to
> use List.from or Map.from respectively to ensure that equality is
> evaluated based on the values of the properties rather than the
> reference.

`final List<int> questionsId = state.questionsId;` should be `final List<int> questionsId = List.from(state.questionsId);`.